# post_order_Iterative_Traversal in java anyone help me

Tags: java

I want do **post_order_Iterative_Traversal** in java.
I wrote this code then have  the following error :

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

plz anyone help me

Comment: Please post your code.  We are not l33t psychic hackers who can remotely view your source code.

Comment: [this is my code][1] [1]: www11.0zz0.com/2012/05/02/13/200934974.png

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.ListIterator`

**Example** -

```
import java.util.*; 
class IteratorTest { 
public static void main(String args[]) { 
// create an array list 
ArrayList al = new ArrayList(); 
// add elements to the array list 
al.add("C"); 
al.add("A"); 
al.add("E"); 
al.add("B"); 
al.add("D"); 
al.add("F"); 
ListIterator litr = al.listIterator(); 
System.out.print("Post Order iteration: "); 
while(litr.hasPrevious()) {

    Object element = litr.previous(); 
    System.out.print(element + " ");

} 
System.out.println(); 
} 
}
```